# Nominatim API for long streets

Tags: openstreetmap, line, nominatim

I'm using the Nominatim API in GeoJSON method to retrieve streets poly line.

For short streets I have no issue and the results are good.

However for long streets the data I'm getting back in the JSON is partial and I'm only getting a small part of the street.

Is there a method which I can use to give me the full street poly line even for long streets?

Here is an example of a street I have issue with and would like to get one JSON file with the all street poly line.

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=hayarkon+tel+aviv&viewbox=34.79%2C31.94%2C34.81%2C31.92&polygon=1

This is the JSON file I'm getting:

http://dev.peek.co.il/ajax/nominatim?address=HaYarkon,Lamed,Tel%20Aviv

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Nominatim to fully understand your question or to know if this is helpful, but have you tried using Overpass Turbo ( http://overpass-turbo.eu/ ). If you are simply trying to get hold of a json file for a set of lines sharing a set of common attributes then this is where I'd start.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by allowing duplicates in the results and setting the limit to a very high number (1000).

You can turn the deduplication off with `dedupe=0`. Its default value is 1. And you can set the limit with limit=.

See: https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Search

This is a request that works for me now:

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?format=json&polygon_geojson=1&dedupe=0&addressdetails=1&q=Thaliastrasse+Vienna
```

Comment: I am aware that the question is >7 years old but I've had the same problem and I wanted others to know an solution using nominatum